# How to change the title in one of Picker's components depending on value of the other component (like in Calendar, Event -> Repeat -> Custom screen)

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

In my app I'm trying to recreate the same logic of behaviour for two PickerViews as it is in native iOS Calendar app, on Event -> Repeat -> Custom screen.

As I figured out, I can change the whole 2d Picker, depending on the value of 1st Picker. Just make few Pickers in the 2d Picker's cell, with different text in its 2d component, and make them `isHidden = true` or `false`, depending on the `selectedRow` of the 1st Picker. So if user chose "Daily" in 1st Picker, I will make visible 2d Picker with number of days in first component and text "days" in second, and other 2d Pickers (with "weeks" and "moths" in second component) - hidden. Doesn't look very laconic for me, but can be used, because when user interacts with the first Picker, the second one is not visible.

But I can't figure out how to make the text of 2d component in 2d Picker to depend on the value of 1st component in the same picker. As we can see in Calendar, when user choose "1" in first component, in second he sees "day", but when he chooses number more then 1, he sees "days" in second component. Can't find how to change titles of Pickers after views did load.

How can I make it work? Really looking forward to read your precious advices.

[Screenshot of this Event -> Repeat -> Custom screen in Calendar app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODCue.png)

**UPD:**

The problem was solved with `.reloadComponent(Int)`.

And there is code I have as a result, hope it'll help someone. :) It contains also the logic for updating titles on the right side of both Picker's cells, and updating text in footer, all the same as in Calendar.

```
class CustomRepeatTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var frequencyPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var frequencyLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var frequensyNumberPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var frequencyNumberLabel: UILabel!

    let frequencyPickerData = [
        ["Minutely", "Hourly","Daily","Weekly"]
    ]

    var frequencyNumberPickerData = [
        ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
    ]

    let units = ["minute", "hour", "day", "week"]

    func updatePicker(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, _ component: Int, _ row: Int) {
        let unit = units[frequencyPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        if pickerView == frequencyPicker {
            frequencyNumberPickerData.remove(at: 1)
            if frequensyNumberPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 0 {
                frequencyNumberPickerData.append([unit])
            } else {
                frequencyNumberPickerData.append([unit + "s"])
            }
            frequensyNumberPicker.reloadComponent(1)
        } else {
            if component == 0 && row == 0 {
                frequencyNumberPickerData.remove(at: 1)
                frequencyNumberPickerData.append([unit])
                frequensyNumberPicker.reloadComponent(1)
            } else {
                frequencyNumberPickerData.remove(at: 1)
                frequencyNumberPickerData.append([unit + "s"])
                frequensyNumberPicker.reloadComponent(1)
            }
        }
    }

    func updateLabels() {
        let selectedRow = frequencyPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        let unit = units[selectedRow]
        let frequencyNumber = frequencyNumberPickerData[0][frequensyNumberPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        var text: String
        var footerText: String

        let frequency = frequencyPickerData[0][selectedRow]
        frequencyLabel.text = frequency

        if frequensyNumberPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) > 0 {
            text = frequencyNumber + " " + unit + "s"
            footerText = frequencyNumber + " " + unit + "s."
        } else {
            text = unit.capitalized
            footerText = unit + "."
        }

        frequencyNumberLabel.text = text

        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 230, height: 30))
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:20, y:0, width:230, height:30))
        label.text = "Repeat will occur every " + footerText
        label.font = label.font.withSize(13)
        label.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
        tableView.tableFooterView?.addSubview(label)
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        if pickerView == frequencyPicker {
            return frequencyPickerData.count
        } else {
            return frequencyNumberPickerData.count
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if pickerView == frequencyPicker {
            return frequencyPickerData[component].count
        } else {
            return frequencyNumberPickerData[component].count
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView == frequencyPicker {
            return frequencyPickerData[component][row]
        } else {
            return String(frequencyNumberPickerData[component][row])
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        updatePicker(pickerView, component, row)
        updateLabels()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        frequencyPicker.delegate = self
        frequencyPicker.dataSource = self
        frequencyPicker.selectRow(1, inComponent: 0, animated: true) //to make selection separators appear

        frequensyNumberPicker.delegate = self
        frequensyNumberPicker.dataSource = self
        frequensyNumberPicker.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true) //to make selection separators appear

        updateLabels()

        frequencyNumberPickerData.append([units[frequencyPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]])
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your code like so far?

Comment: Simply reload the 2nd component when the selection of the first changes.

Comment: @Carpsen90 added the code

Comment: @rmaddy you mean in `didSelectRow` to append new array to my `frequencyNumberPickerData` and then use `frequensyNumberPicker.reloadAllComponents()` to reload the picker?